# Understanding Gradle project dependancies, Gradle site example seems incomplete

Tags: java, gradle, build

I am trying to understand Gradle build dependencies but am having trouble using the examples on the Gradle website and wondered if anyone could help.

In the [Adding dependencies to a task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks) section of their website there is the following code to be saved in **build.gradle**:

```
project('projectA') {
    task taskX {
        dependsOn ':projectB:taskY'
        doLast {
            println 'taskX'
        }
    }
}

project('projectB') {
    task taskY {
        doLast {
            println 'taskY'
        }
    }
}
```

They say that the **Output of gradle -q taskX** is:

```
> gradle -q taskX
taskY
taskX
```

But I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/tmp/x/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'x'.
> Project with path ':projectA' could not be found in root project 'x'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

With `--stacktrace` I get the following:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException: Project with path ':projectA' could not be found in root project 'x'.
```

NOTE: This `build.gradle` file is the only file in the `/tmp/x` folder.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2012-12-21 00:00:00 UTC
Revision:     none

Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.3 compiled on July 19 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation 25.191-b12)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-43-generic amd64
```

Comment: you need to create/configure a `settings.gradle` file in order to declare/configure sub-projects. See more info here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html . You also need to create two sub-directories `projectA`  and `projectB` of course, to create the two subprojects.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this example you are trying to implement, makes assumption that you have a multi-project build ( then it explains how to create dependencies between tasks from the sub-projects) => it seems you have currently a simple mono-project build, that's why you get this error. `projectA` is unknown to Gradle.

Comment: Thanks, if you add those 2 comments as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [chatper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks) from the documentation explains how to create dependencies between tasks from different (sub)projects of a same build (task `X`from project `projectA` depends on task `Y` from project `projectB` in the example).

So you need to setup a multi-project build before trying to execute the given example: see basics in multi-project build [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

In your case: you need to:

1) create two subproject directories 'projectA' and 'projectB'

2) Create the required `settings.gradle` file in root project directory,  to declare/include the two subprojects

```
include ("projectA" , "projectB")
```